# AWS EC2 t3.micro instance sufficiently stable for spring boot services

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am new to AWS and recently set up a free t3.micro instance. My goal is to achieve a stable hosting of an Angular application with 2 spring boot services. I got everything working, but after a while, the spring boot services are not reachable anymore. When i redeploy the service it will run again. The spring boot services are packed as jar and after the deployment the process is started as a java process.

I thought AWS guarantees permanent availability out of the box. Do i need some more setup such as autoscaling to achieve the desired uptime of the services or is the t3.micro instance not suffienciently performant, so that i need to upgrade to a stronger instance to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It depends :)

I think you did the right thing by starting with a small instance type and avoid over provisioning in the first place. T3 instance types are generally beneficial for 'burst' usage scenarios i.e. your application sporadically needs a compute spike but not a persistent one. T3 instance types usually work with credits based system, where you instance 'earns' credits when it is idle, and that buffer is always available in times of need (but only until consumed entirely). Then you need to wait for some time window again and earn the credits back.

For your current problem, I think first approach can be to get an idea of the current usage by going through the 'Monitoring' tab on the EC2 instance details page. This will help you understand if the needs are more compute related or i/o related and then you can choose an appropriate instance type from :

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types

Next step could also be to profile your application and understand the memory, compute utilisation better. AWS does guarantee availability/durability of resources, but how you consume those resources is more of an application thing, which AWS does not guarantee/control

For your ideas around, autoscaling and availability, it again depends on what your needs are in terms of cost, outages in AWS data centres etc. To have a reliable production setup, you could consider them, but not something really important in the first place.